# Spring property initialization

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-ioc

I have an xml configurable Spring context with the following property placeholders:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        properties-ref="dbProperties" location="classpath:logmessages.properties" order="2"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" order="1"/>
```

DB properties configuration bean is as follows:

```
<bean id="dbProperties"
    class="com.example.DatabasePropertiesLoader">
    <property name="path" value="${db.path}"/>
</bean>
```

As it comes from the name, this bean loads some properties from the database, for example endpoints and credentials to other services. However, to access the database that keeps this properties it also needs credentials, which are kept in application.properties:

```
public class DatabasePropertiesLoader extends AbstractFactoryBean<Properties> {

   private String path;

   @Override
   protected Properties createInstance() throws Exception {
      // logic loading properties
   }

   @Override
   public Class<Properties> getObjectType() {
       return Properties.class;
   }
```

}

Path property kept in application.properties file:

```
db.path=localhost:7777
```

As you see, this bean requires "path" property to be injected to be created.

However, it can't be done, because injected value is null. I guess that Spring only knows about application.properties file, not about its contents. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You **need to tell** spring to use the properties as below.

```
@Value("${db.path}")
private String path;
```

Comment: I'm using XML configuration
This string does exactly the same:
    <property name="path" value="${db.path}"/>

Comment: But, you are referring other property file? "properties-ref="dbProperties" location="classpath:logmessages.properties"

Comment: I have 2 property placeholders. Please, read the question before answering evidently and incorrectly